# Connect to metamask and WalletConnect using web3-react

Tags: web3js, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, react, walletconnect

I have been using web3-react to connect different wallets:
I want to connect to metamask extension with the help of

```
import { WalletConnectConnector } from "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector";
```

For wallectConnect

```
export const walletConnector = new WalletConnectConnector({
  rpc: {
    3: `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_ID}`,
  },
});
```

If I activate above walletConnector it only shows QR code and DOESNOT include metamask (injected provider) option.

Or else what is the option to integrate @walletconnect/web3-provider with web3-react

Answer (score 1):

you want to use InjectedConnector,

```
import { InjectedConnector } from '@web3-react/injected-connector' 

const MetaMask = new InjectedConnector({ supportedNetworks: [1, 4] });
const connectors = { MetaMask };
```

Then you want to wrap your app with:

```
 <Web3Provider
      connectors={connectors}
      libraryName={"ethers.js"}
    > <YOUR_APP/> 
</Web3Provider>
```

Then use it with something like this

```
import { useWeb3Context } from "web3-react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const context = useWeb3Context();

useEffect(() => {
    context.setConnector("MetaMask");
}, []);
```

If you use MetaMask option in WalletConnect I think its just to mobile Metamask